# Material-ui style type override

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, material-ui

I'd like to modify `MuiIconButton-root` class when I use MuiSvgIcon with `fontSizeSmall`.

```
import React from 'react'
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSvgIcon: {
      fontSizeSmall: {
        padding: "5px"
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function Root(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MyApp />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

I've modified `MuiSvgIcon`, but it can't modify `MuiButtonBase-root`.
Is there any way to override the padding value of `MuiIconButton-root` when I use small `MuiSvgIcon`?

Following the picture:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you may follow the official document here https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can override the style of root like this, I am not creating your exact scenario but I am going to show you the same functionality with a button from Material UI, first get all the files needed:

```
npm install @material-ui/styles
npm install @material-ui/core
```

and then:

```
    //other react imports
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'; //you need to include this to change the style
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'; //this is just the button

const useStyles = theme => ({
    root: {
        '& > *': {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
        },
    },
    button: {
        fontSize: "16px",
        fontWeight: "600",
        textAlign: "center",
        border: "none",
        cursor: "pointer",
        color: "#fff",
        backgroundColor: "#C8385E"
    }
});

class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>
            <Button
                className={classes.button}
                variant="contained" component="span">
                BUTTON TEXT
            </Button>
        </div>);
    }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(Welcome);
```

you need to export the class like shown above, include the "withStyles" and pass in the styles that you have, here its called "useStyles" and then pass the class name. this way you can edit the styles in the UseStyles and it will actually show those changes on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.